# kivy bluetooth and other api for android and ios

Tags: android, python, ios, pycharm, kivy

Does anyone know how to implement Plyer in pycharm? 
I have seen that using plyer I can use many APIs for android and ios, but in the page on github there isn't a guide to install it. I put this in pycharm:

```
from plyer import tts
```

And tried,

```
from plyer import email
```

But it gives me an error.

https://github.com/kivy/plyer

Comment: what error, please put it in question

Answer (score 0):

Plyer is a python module. You need to install it to your local python installation using `pip`, either from pypi (the result that appears with e.g. `pip search plyer`), or possibly directly from github since it's actively developed and the pypi version may lack some apis, in which case you'd want something like `pip2 install git+https://github.com/kivy/plyer.git`.

Comment: I suggest googling how to use pip in general, this is a normal python thing.

Comment: problem is that when i use upgrade pip or instal the terminal install it in defaul python path, not in kivy.app

Comment: Because kivy.app includes and uses a separate python installation with its own pip

Comment: so how can i install it in the interpreter in kivy.app ??